# Generating strings and identifying substrings is very slow

Tags: string, substring, rust

I'd like to benchmark certain operations in Rust, but I seem to be having some trouble:

```
fn main(){

    let needle   = (0..100).map(|_| "b").collect::<String>();
    let haystack = (0..100_000).map(|_| "a").collect::<String>();

    println!("Data ready.");

    for _ in 0..1_000_000 {
        if haystack.contains( &needle ) {
            // Stuff...
        }
    }

}
```

The above takes a very long time to complete while the same operation in Ruby finishes in around 4.5 seconds:

```
needle   = 'b' * 100
haystack = 'a' * 100_000

puts 'Data ready.'

1_000_000.times do
    haystack.include? needle
end
```

I can't help but think that I'm doing something fundamentally wrong.
What would be the proper way to do this in Rust?

```
rustc 1.0.0 (a59de37e9 2015-05-13) (built 2015-05-14)
ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-linux]
```

Comment: For those who wonder: in this case, it is not an optimizations issue. Even with optimizations turned on the rust version is still very long to run.

Comment: I *think* it could be that `contains` for strings takes additional actions to handle UTF-8 properly, however, when I went to check the speed of `contains` for regular slices I found out that Rust does not even have one o_O. My naive implementation still was very slow.

Comment: Tried this for myself; Ruby took 5s, Rust took *7 minutes*.  A quick squiz through Rust's implementation (see [`libcore/str/pattern.rs`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.0.0/src/libcore/str/pattern.rs#L390)) makes it look like Rust's searcher is *completely naive*.  If the Ruby implementation is doing anything even remotely clever, it wouldn't be surprising at all that Rust is so much slower.  Either way, looks worthy of a performance issue being filed.

Comment: BTW, python version is also as fast as Ruby.

Comment: And Java version is even faster, probably due to JIT optimizations (first few thousands checks are slower, others are blazingly fast). Indeed, it seems Rust std library could be optimized.

Comment: Filed an issue: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/25483

Comment: Is the misspelling of *haystack* intentional ?

Comment: @MatthieuM. Nope, fixed. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A fix for this issue was merged today. That means it should be part of the next nightly, and will be expected to be released in Rust 1.3. The fix revived the [Two-way substring search](http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~lecroq/string/node26.html) implementation that Rust used to have and adapted it to the new [Pattern API](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/str/pattern/trait.Pattern.html) in the standard library.

The Two-way algorithm is a good match for Rust's libcore since it is a linear time substring search algorithm that uses O(1) space and needs no dynamic allocation.

The particular implementation contains a simple addition that will reject this particular query in the question extremely quickly (and no, it was not written because of this question, it was part of the old code too).

During setup the searcher computes a kind of fingerprint for the needle: For each byte in the needle, take its low 6 bits, which is a number 0-63, then set the corresponding bit in the `u64` variable `byteset`.

```
let byteset = needle.iter().fold(0, |a, &b| (1 << ((b & 0x3f) as usize)) | a);
```

Since the needle only contains 'b's, the value of byteset will have only the 34th bit set (`98 & 63 == 34`).

Now we can test any byte whether it can possibly be part of the needle or not. If its corresponding bit isn't set in `byteset`, the needle cannot match. Each byte we test in the haystack in this case will be 'a' (`97 & 63 == 33`), and it can't match. So the algorithm will read a single byte, reject it, and then skip the needle's length.

```
fn byteset_contains(&self, byte: u8) -> bool {
    (self.byteset >> ((byte & 0x3f) as usize)) & 1 != 0
}

// Quickly skip by large portions unrelated to our substring
if !self.byteset_contains(haystack[self.position + needle.len() - 1]) {
    self.position += needle.len();
    continue 'search;
}
```

[From `libcore/str/pattern.rs` in rust-lang/rust](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/7fc0675f35b78d86ad2decd9fe22afd238eda274/src/libcore/str/pattern.rs#L864-L889)

Comment: What would the Rust performance be if both the needle and haystack were random data, compared to Ruby? Is there something to be gained in that case by Rust's overall design?

Comment: I think both should search for random needles much slower than the "bb.." in "aa.." query. I think they are on a level playing field. Note that the new string search in Rust is still written in bounds-checked safe Rust, and it seems to be very competitive anyway.

Comment: I'm interested if you do new performance comparisons between rust and ruby, using this new impl.

Comment: By much slower I mean that on my laptop, the "bb.." in "aa.." query would bench at rejecting 30 GB of haystack per second (since it reads only a fraction of the bytes), while a more normal string search would bench at 300 MB haystack per second.